# Reversing the input of a merkle tree

Tags: merkle

I'm trying to reverse the input of a Merkle tree by comparing a proof from the original tree and the proof I am generating myself.

Original proof:

```js
[
    "0x738cf34d25d0f7f2b3267982fae5217128178fa8c9ef62278ac458e28c5821b7",
    "0xf4474db66b110943989428179bb76a99758fe18c7484c7ba6bb171853fb2f672",
    "0xf03a304123fb20a25b72bc4a8adffd60095c3621cd4ab010479f2df5da56c744",
    "0x4cbc2a3af5334ad82c30ef0a2cc4839f7b6fe6488c26dca467cf4ec171b6b7a0",
    "0x796b541b652d1d2a65ce9aa28bbb5aaef62177451ea4bbc15ae7bfa5168d468b",
    "0x1a94cf9edd955fb8df6b5e84a8ba94dc3192e98453dc808c135bdc52b4bf18f6",
    "0xa76175d0ef45defc5b12e498dc8d9ffe1c657d73ad550768c5e840cf0d336980",
    "0x498c55290416d75dd9716902b2654166d6f5e8be09104edfd56bd95dbe2adc90",
    "0x6867a748e728fe4673484ac76c6a7fda1794a23950b4c2587c24a00671c084fe",
    "0x74b6b61b99e32e54244fd1339f9b8fe2368cc0989677f5cf69816d03a47480f7",
    "0x011e5b59c850bf6ce3211d78c370568048e93d92487c83e637c0abdd018bf33e",
    "0x1fefa79cdb65d1e4a91c784fca4db88382ffc10406ee96189a1b3c2102a359c1",
    "0x53a5654d0e5f424fcf1095b357d5d62917ef9030cfbd54bdbe5cb078b3f0508d",
    "0xd70c9fcdaaa18649df0c2ae2e29498a3bdc0269448e948228d02addaf22dc530",
]
```

My proof:

```js
[
  '0x738cf34d25d0f7f2b3267982fae5217128178fa8c9ef62278ac458e28c5821b7',
  '0xf4474db66b110943989428179bb76a99758fe18c7484c7ba6bb171853fb2f672',
  '0xf03a304123fb20a25b72bc4a8adffd60095c3621cd4ab010479f2df5da56c744',
  '0x4cbc2a3af5334ad82c30ef0a2cc4839f7b6fe6488c26dca467cf4ec171b6b7a0',
  '0x796b541b652d1d2a65ce9aa28bbb5aaef62177451ea4bbc15ae7bfa5168d468b',
  '0x1a94cf9edd955fb8df6b5e84a8ba94dc3192e98453dc808c135bdc52b4bf18f6',
  '0xa76175d0ef45defc5b12e498dc8d9ffe1c657d73ad550768c5e840cf0d336980',
  '0x498c55290416d75dd9716902b2654166d6f5e8be09104edfd56bd95dbe2adc90',
  '0x6867a748e728fe4673484ac76c6a7fda1794a23950b4c2587c24a00671c084fe',
  '0x74b6b61b99e32e54244fd1339f9b8fe2368cc0989677f5cf69816d03a47480f7',
  '0x011e5b59c850bf6ce3211d78c370568048e93d92487c83e637c0abdd018bf33e',
  '0x1fefa79cdb65d1e4a91c784fca4db88382ffc10406ee96189a1b3c2102a359c1',
  '0x53a5654d0e5f424fcf1095b357d5d62917ef9030cfbd54bdbe5cb078b3f0508d',
  '0x8d41dc10f4b775fb64acbb16141b980b1530e99fc45150a2b7856c1c7ac1816f'
]
```

As you can see I have successfully matched it expect the very last element. Is this just coincidence or is there a common explanation as to why they would be almost identical? It seems like I'm close to solving it but maybe there's a simple change I could make?

Thanks for any help

Comment: So you are staring from all the original proofs, getting all the inputs, and use the inputs to generate the proofs, then compare with the original ones. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @0xSanson yes that's correct